# Eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $P$ is positive definite matrix and $(I-aP)$ matrix which has eigenvalues less than $1$ in magnitude.
Show that maximal eigenvalue of matrix $P$ is less than $2$.

Comment: Try fixing your question. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The problem is that for me aslo is not very much clear :)

Comment: Maybe like this... If P is positive definite matrix and (I-aP) matrix which has eigenvalues less than 1 in magnitude. Show that maximal eigenvalue of matrix P is less than 2.

Comment: What is a in $(I-aP)$?

Comment: I is identity matrix(unit),P positive definite matrix,and a some constant

Answer (score 2):

This question cannot be correct without some additional condition on either $a$ or $P.$  For example, let $a=\frac{1}{1000}$ and let $P=500I$.  Then $(I-aP)=\frac{1}{2}I$ has eigenvalues equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and $P$ is positive definite with eigenvalues of $500.$